# error handling in gprolog?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

In order to run a group of queries in a simple query, I have tagged these queries and use `forall/2` to call them:

```
query_all :-
    forall(query(Q), (Q ->
        format('yes: ~w~n',[Q]) ;
        format('no : ~w~n',[Q]))).
```

so if I define something like `query(true).`, I'll be able to see `yes: true` from the output.

The problem here is that `query( ... )` do not always exist, when prolog can't find anything that tagged `query`, `forall/2` will fail and cause exception saying "error(existence_error(procedure,query/1),forall/2)"

I want to handle this exception, but not to break the whole control flow.

I know [catch/3](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc68) would help me but I don't know how to use it, my code is:

```
catch(query_all, error(existence_error(procedure,_),_), recovery).

recovery :-
    format('error occurred.~n',[]).
```

but prolog says "native code procedure catch/3 cannot be redefined".
Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either declare `query/1` as dynamic in your code adding this line:

```
:-dynamic(query/1).
```

or use `catch/3` as you suggested, however you don't have to redefine it but use it instead, e.g:

```
query_all :-
  catch(
    forall(query(Q), (Q ->
        format('yes: ~w~n',[Q]) ;
        format('no : ~w~n',[Q]))),
        error(existence_error(procedure, _), _), format('error occurred.~n', [])).
```